# Mongoose Sorting issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection

```
var mycoll = new Schema({
    col1: { type: String,required: true,}
  , col2: {type: String} 
  , mydate: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now,index:1} 
  etcetc
}, { collection: 'info' });
```

I a building a query based on mongoose like below

```
Info.statics.FindbyPage= function (callback, skip, limit) {

var infos = this.find();

infos.sort({ mydate: 1}).skip(skip).limit(limit);

res = infos.exec(callback)

}
```

**the problem is that the result is not sorted by mydate, if i remove the limit and skip things the results will load all and they're well sorted once i put skip and limit the resutls is sorted but some date are missing ...**

any help??? one thing to notice is i tried every possibilty in the sort param

i am using mongoose v3

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in the Mongo shell (e.g. invoke "db.infos.find().sort({ mydate: 1}).skip(skip).limit(limit)") and see if you have the same issue. It's usually helpful to remove language or framework specific things from your question if possible. The functionality in your question should work. Also consider adding the resultset of your query.

Comment: @RemonvanVliet i was able to replicate this issue in the mongo shell. if i increase the limit the problem goes away

Comment: I also have the same exact issue right now, have no idea what to do. MongoDB docs say that sort applies first. But now, somehow, it doesn't.